# slice an image using canvas into div elements?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css

I load an image, then using canvas I crop it into individual squares. How can I assign the cropped selections (which are drawn on a canvas) into individual div elements? I understand that i can create multiple canvases and insert them inside multiple divs, but that would hurt the performance.
Any way of taking a canvas and converting it into an image object or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `canvas.toDataURL()` to set the image of your canvas as the `background-image` of your `<div>`s ?

If it works, you should be able to use the image of the canvas as a CSS sprite.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a canvas. Just use the image as background for `div` elements, and use background position to show different parts of the image.

Example:

```
<div id="nw"></div>
<div id="ne"></div>
<div id="sw"></div>
<div id="se"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(someimage.jpg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nw { background-position: 0 0; }
#ne { background-position: -100px 0; }
#sw { background-position: 0 -100px; }
#se { background-position: -100px -100px; }
```